# Unit test : autocompletion is not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I have an angular 4 app, I use VS code, and I've started to write my first unit test :

```
describe('DeclarationUtilService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DeclarationUtilService]
    });
    this.accident = new Accident();

    this.injuredPerson = new InjuredPerson();
    this.injuredPerson.lesionNature = new LesionNature();
    this.injuredPerson.personType = new PersonType();
    this.injuredPerson.personType.id = 1;

    this.accident.injuredPersons.push(this.injuredPerson);


  });

  it('#refreshDeclarationCategorization should return FR0 true for internal', inject([DeclarationUtilService], (service: DeclarationUtilService) => {

    this.injuredPerson.personType.internal = true;
    const declarationCateg = service.refreshDeclarationCategorization(this.accident);
    expect(declarationCateg.fr0)
      .toBe(true, 'should be FR0');
  }));
```

I've tried to set some variables in the "beforeEach" part that I plan to use in each test. Test is working, but when I try to use variables set in beforeEach, autocompletion is not working, which is not handy...
Do I miss something somewhere ? Or is it a bug with VS Code?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should create an instance of component that you are testing and avoid using `this`.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And then in your case, it will be like -

```
component.injuredPerson.personType.internal = true;
```

Also, instead of of creating instances using `new`, you can simply add providers using TestBed itself.